# Memory usage while debugging C++ using VS2013

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory, heap-memory

Running a console program for windows (c++ vs2013, compiler 2008) under debug (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and it takes about 800Mb of memory.

When I run it without debugging <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it takes 150Mb, start release from cmd - 150 Mb.

System - x64, x32 build works normal.

Its normal, that program takes 150Mb, but can someone describe me, what happening, when I attach the debugger and how can I avoid so big memory allocation?

*edit:
VLD saids, that i have 600kb memory leaks, and i know where they are.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638995/what-are-the-negative-consequences-of-turning-debug-heap-off-no-debug-heap-1

Comment: Why is it a problem that the programmed being debugged takes 800 MB? How do you measure this?

Comment: @MSalters, by Task Manager. Its no problem in debug - it will be problem, in release.

Comment: @HansPassant, yea! _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 its ok, ty